# Java Basic: Access variable out of the class

Tags: java, junit

```
    Class Controller{

      public String acceptTick() {
        if (button_Pressed) {
          turnCarLightRed();
          turnPedLightGreen();
          tick=0;
          button_Pressed = false;
    } else{ 
        switch (tick) {
        // at sec 1
        case 1:
            turnCarLightYellow();// carlight is yellow
            String test = turnCarLightRed(); // Car light is now red
            turnPedLightGreen();// PedLight is Green
            break;
        // after 10 sec
        case 10:
            turnPedLightRed();// Pedlight is Red
            turnCarLightGreen();// CarLight is Green
            break;
        // after another 15 seconds
        case 25:
            turnCarLightYellow(); 
            turnCarLightRed();
            turnPedLightGreen();
            tick = 0;
            break;
        }
      }
    return currentCarLight;
    }
}
```

In this Controller class I have a method called `aceeptTick()` which has switch case and it has **String test** variable. Now I want to access this variable in my new class called **ControllerTest** can you suggest me how I can access this variable?

```
 class ControllerTest{
   public void testController() {
   do {
        ob.acceptTick();
        ++tick;
        if (tick == 1) {
          String car = //here I want to access "test variable"                                                      
          assertEquals("Green", car);
          String ped = ob.turnPedLightGreen();
          assertEquals("Green", ped);
        }
    } while (tick < 60);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the accept!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, you go for:

```
class A {
  public String whatever = "bla";
}

class B {
  void foo() {
    String other = new A().whatever;
}
```

You create a **field** in class A, make that public (or you leave out the keyword, then the visibility is "package protected"; allowing for access in the same package); and then you simply need an instance of the other class and can directly use that variable.

But conceptually, the answer: you don't do that.

Good OO programming is about **hiding** implementation details; and more: when you make fields public, you allow any other class to **change** the content of that field!

To address part, you would rather go for:

```
class A {
  private String whatever = ...
  public String getWhatever() { return whatever };
```

That allows other classes to **query** that field; without having the possibility to change it.

And making the final step: in good OO you avoid even that. Good OO is about *behavior*, not *state*. In other words: you don't ask another object to give you some value to then  make a decision based on that. Instead, you put a nice method on that other class that *does* what you need. The principle behind that is called [Tell dont ask](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TellDontAsk.html)!

And beyond that: you do **not** write **one** unit test to test multiple conditions.

You want to write **one** test **per** condition. In other words: your test code should not be looping. Instead, you call your class under test with the required parameters. Which shines on **another** problem in your whole setup: it should **not** be the test cases that *ticks* your production class.

Long story short: you should step back and learn a bit about the basics of good OO before further diving into unit tests, too.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to declare '**test**' as a class variable and provide a getter-Method for it.
Or you make your '**acceptTick()**'-Method return '**test**' (as you don't seem to use the actual return value of the method)

Answer (score 0):

Change your Controller class to have a public variable:

```
Class Controller{
    public String test; // variable added here
    public String acceptTick() {
        if (button_Pressed) {
        turnCarLightRed();
        turnPedLightGreen();
```

then remove `String` from this line `String test = turnCarLightRed();`

Now you can access the variable like so from the ControllerTest class:
`String car = ob.test;`

Answer (score 0):

Why not write a method that in your class that returns the test string, and make that method public so it can be used outside the class.